# Validate upload size

Tags: c#, file-upload

I have the following code below:

```
MultipartMemoryStreamProvider result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider());
HttpContent content = results.Contents.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name.Contains("FileContent"));

byte[] data = await content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

if (data.Length > 51200)
{
    // block upload with more than 50mb of size
}
```

Now this is not working because even 2mb file is being blocked. I searched and saw that 50mb in kb is 51200.

Comment: sure your webserver isnt configured to reject files bigger than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already read official msdn [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.length(v=vs.110).aspx)?

The method Length():

> gets the length in bytes of the stream.

Actually, 51200 bytes are equals to 0,05 Mb.
Have you tried to change it?

If you need to block upload with more than 50mb of size, you need to set it to:
50 Mb = 52,428,800 bytes.

Comment: This worked for me. Changed the value to 52428000. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Im not so sure but you can try this:

```
double filesize = data.Length / 2048
```

remember `1024kb == 1MB` and `1024byte == 1kb` that's is why `data.Length /2048` to get the Megabyte

The Content value of `filesize == MB`

```
 if(filesize>50)
```

something like that...

Comment: I tried this one but the validation is still failing for 10mb files.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line in your web.config and it will not allow beyond the size specified to be uploaded from application

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="1200" maxRequestLength="15000" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100" enableVersionHeader="true" />
```

`maxRequestLength="15000"` will allow maximum to 15 MB and post which will through exception, similarly you can specify as per your requirement.

`Config` file will check for upload file size and you do not have to write specific code for the same